# Recommended plugin for virtual SVN

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-plugin

Is there any plug-in in grails which can implements virtually all Subversion features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct plug-in available in grails for subversion features.
**IMHO:** You should use **[SVNKit](http://svnkit.com/)** for subversion features.

SVNKit is an Open Source, pure Java software library for working with the Subversion version control system. It implements virtually all Subversion features and provides API to work with Subversion working copies, access and manipulate Subversion repositories.